# Scheme write function that return a function

Tags: lambda, scheme

I'm having trouble defining a function that, according to a given param "flag", return a function in Scheme:

```
    (define con-func
  (lambda(f a flag)
    (cond (= flag 0) (lambda (x) (f (+ x a)))
          (= flag 1) (lambda (x) (f (- x a)))
          (= flag 2) (lambda (x) (f (* x a)))
          (= flag 3) (lambda (x) (f (/ x a)))
          (else (lambda (x) f x)))))
```

I receive an error: `lambda: bad syntax in: lambda <br />`
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No, your added parentheses are in the wrong place. `cond` clauses are of the form `(test result ...)`, so the first expression in the parentheses should be your test, followed by the result.

```
(define (con-func f a flag)
  (cond ((= flag 0) (lambda (x) (f (+ x a))))
        ((= flag 1) (lambda (x) (f (- x a))))
        ((= flag 2) (lambda (x) (f (* x a))))
        ((= flag 3) (lambda (x) (f (/ x a))))
        (else f)))
```

Of course, in this case, since you're testing the same value against a bunch of constants, you can simplify to using a `case`:

```
(define (con-func f a flag)
  (case flag
    ((0) (lambda (x) (f (+ x a))))
    ((1) (lambda (x) (f (- x a))))
    ((2) (lambda (x) (f (* x a))))
    ((3) (lambda (x) (f (/ x a))))
    (else f)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The lambda that you are returning is already 'closing' over the values of `f` and `a`.  Why not close over the value of `operator` as well.  Like this:

```
(define (con-func f a flag)
  (let ((operator 
         (case flag
          ((0) +)
          ((1) -)
          ((2) *)
          ((3) /)
          (else (lambda (a b) a)))))
    (lambda (x) (f (operator x a)))))
```

Answer (score -1):

I was missing a parenthesis..

Correct syntax is:

```
    (define con-func
  (lambda(f a flag)
    (cond (= flag 0) ((lambda (x) (f (+ x a))))
          (= flag 1) ((lambda (x) (f (- x a))))
          (= flag 2) ((lambda (x) (f (* x a))))
          (= flag 3) ((lambda (x) (f (/ x a))))
          (else (lambda (x) f x)))))
```

Comment: Since your parentheses are in the wrong place, your function will always return 0, no matter what.

Comment: Sorry for correcting you Chris, but the function works correctly.

Comment: Not true. I just tested your function in Racket, with the incorrect parenthesis placement, and the results are exactly as I mentioned.